# Secret message in "Secret messages"?

Tags: rock

It is common knowledge, that Electric Light Orchestra managed to encode a lot of secret messages in their album "Secret Messages", usually by inverting them (you have to invert part of song to listen them back - for instance, beginning of first song, "Secret messages" is the same as epilogue of "Rock and roll is king").

What bothers me though is that in the background of the first song there can be heard a series of beeps, which are not regular and that can be easily seen when you open the song in sound editor, like Audacity and view the spectrogram:

[image]

It is quite hard though to isolate them, because a lot of other instruments and voices kicks in and drowns the signal.

Did anyone managed to try to decode this *secret message* as well?